# How to write a spring interceptor which will validate all request before a generic check

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

Need to intercept all incoming requests to validate them. 
In case of success invoke controller, else respond back with an error message to the calling jsp page.

How to achieve this implementation using spring 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and you will have  an interceptor of your own. In this extended class, override method `postHandle` . In this method, you will get an object of type `ModelAndView` as a parameter,using which you can change target view as you need.